# How to solve cannot read property 'push' of undefined in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

While I am adding values to a sub document, in command prompt it shows the error
 like cannot read property `push`. How can I solve this?

Here's `my schema code` with the help of these I gave values to parent schema
 but I'm not able to give the values to this sub document:

```
var venueSchema = new Schema({
    name:  {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    },
    address:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// create a schema
var batchSchema = new Schema({
   batchname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    activityname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    time: {
    type:String,
    required:true
    },
    duration: {
    type:String,
    required:true
    },
    classtype: {
    type:String,
    required:true
    },
    trainer: {
    type:String,
    required:true
    },
    price:{
    type:Currency,
    required:true,
    unique:true
    },

    venue:[venueSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

And my `Routing code`:

```
batchRouter.route('/:batchId/venue')
.post(function (req, res, next) {
    Batches.findById(req.params.batchId, function (err, batch) {
        if (err) throw err;
      batch.venue.push(req.body);
        batch.save(function (err, batch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Updated venue!');
            res.json(batch);
        });
    });
})
```

Here parent document is `batchSchema` and sub-document is `venueSchema`. After
 creation of batch I will get an `id`. With the help of this `id` I am trying to       add values to venue at that time it shows me the error at
 `batch.venue.push(req.body);`

Comment: Write `batch.venue = batch.venue || [];` before push.

Comment: What you are expecting in batch.venue? Just log it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you get means that:

1. You don't get an error from the database because `if (err) throw err;` doesn't fire
2. Your `batch.venue` is undefined because you get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`
3. Your `batch` is defined because you don't get `Cannot read property 'venue' of undefined`

It means that you have a connection with the database, you get a document with the ID that you want, but it doesn't have the property `venue` that you expect to be present and to be an array.

Instead of:

```
batch.venue.push(req.body);
```

you can use:

```
if (!Array.isArray(batch.venue)) {
    batch.venue = [];
}
batch.venue.push(req.body);
```

or:

```
if (Array.isArray(batch.venue)) {
    batch.venue.push(req.body);
} else {
    batch.venue = [req.body];
}
```

or something like that, i.e. you need to check if you have an array before you try to push elements to it. If you don't have an array then you will have to create a new one.

Answer (score 7):

Router();

In this method If we are not mention () this also it will show the push error...

```
const express = require('express');
const routerd = express.Router();
const Ninja = require('./models/ninja');

routerd.delete('/ninja:/id', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    res.send({type : 'DELETE'});
}).catch(next);

module.exports = routerd;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved as:

```
Batches.findById(req.params.batchId, function (err, batch) {
    if (err) throw err;
  const a = req.body.venue;
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++ )
  {
   batch.venue.push(req.body.venue[i]);
  }

    batch.save(function (err, batch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Updated venue!');
        res.json(batch);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we get this error when we do not import the router properly.

the example code snippet

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/signout", (req, res) =>{
  res.send("user sign out")
 })


module.exports = router;
```